# tracking specific request and response parameters in java application

Tags: java, tracking

I'm trying to get track of specific parameters of my request and response object and then retrieve it for another report. for example if i have a person object as request object i want to get track of only it's name and family and not the age.I'm aware of Spring Actuator, but i want a framework or best practice to implement or use it in my project. is there any best practice or framework in java for this purpose?
i tried to search this but all i get is best practices for monitoring important metrics of application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filters to track request and response. Example is available at [Spring Boot Filter example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter)

Comment: currently using an aspect to track these parameters. but i was wondering for best practice of track like how to determine which parameters of object(annotations or maybe database structure) to track and with which structure it decided to store it. thanks

Comment: It all depends on your requirements - what, why and where you want to track? What disadvantage do you feel with Aspects based approach?

Comment: well now i have to keep tracking information of each object in database, that which inner objects i have to track. i have a query to retrieve this data and more queries to insert values in database. i was thinking of moving it to annotation base tracking but it has complexity and problem of nested objects which i want to track in one condition and not track in another condition. so i was wondering what is the best practice for implementing field base track in java. but i couldn't find something about this requirement.