# Is there a way to access Spring controller parameters outside of the controller class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have Spring acpect which triggers around every controller method in my application. And in the body of aspect i want to acess all request parameters which are declared in method signature. Is there an easy way to do it avoiding reflection?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but this may help:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19327318/259889

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59151424/1776132 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try **Around Advice**

```
@Around("yourMethods()")
    public Object someOperation(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        Object retval = pjp.proceed();
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        String methodName = pjp.getSignature().getName();
        logger.info("Execution of " + methodName + " took " + 
          TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(end - start) + " ms");
        return retval;
    }
```

Here ProceedingJoinPoint will have all the parameters so you can use them and don't forget to return object otherwise program will break.